# the crawler doesn't stop at the max page limit and keeps on crawling

Tags: database, express, recursion, request, web-crawler

I have made a recursive crawl function to crawl webpages. the maxPage is limited to 200, but the crawler keeps on crawling and making requests even if it has reached the max limit of crawled page. When i also check the crawledPages table in mySQL database it has more than 200 crawled pages.

I have tried to stop it using conditions but I failed. also i used a process.exit() whenever it reaches the maxPage limit which worked but I don't want the server to be shutted down.

here is the code :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { validateToken } = require("../middlewares/AuthMiddleware");
const { Crawledpage } = require("../models");
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const urlModule = require("url");

router.get("/crawl", validateToken, (req, res) => {
  const baseUrl = req.query.url;
  const maxDepth = parseInt(req.query.depth || "3", 10); // Default to depth of 3 if not provided
  const maxPages = parseInt(req.query.maxPages || "200", 10);

  // Use an object to keep track of visited URLs to avoid infinite loops
  const visitedUrls = {};

  // Use an array to keep track of crawled pages
  const crawledPages = [];

  // Keep track of the number of crawled pages
  let crawledPagesCount = 0;

  // Define a recursive function to crawl each page
  async function crawl(url, depth) {
    // Exit the function if the maximum number of pages has been reached
    if (crawledPagesCount >= maxPages) {
      console.log(
        `Maximum number of pages (${maxPages}) reached. Stopping crawling.`
      );
      return;
    }
    if (visitedUrls[url] || depth > maxDepth) {
      return;
    }

    visitedUrls[url] = true;

    let currentRequest;
    currentRequest = request(url, async (error, response, html) => {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);

        const title = $("title").text();
        const titleLength = title.length;

        const metaDescription = $('meta[name="description"]').attr("content");
        const metaDescriptionLength = metaDescription
          ? metaDescription.length
          : 0;

        const ogTitle = $('meta[property="og:title"]').attr("content");
        const ogTitleCharactersCount = ogTitle ? ogTitle.length : 0;

        const twitterTitle = $('meta[name="twitter:title"]').attr("content");
        const twitterTitleCharactersCount = twitterTitle
          ? twitterTitle.length
          : 0;

        const ogDescription = $('meta[property="og:description"]').attr(
          "content"
        );
        const ogDescriptionCharactersCount = ogDescription
          ? ogDescription.length
          : 0;

        const twitterDescription = $('meta[name="twitter:description"]').attr(
          "content"
        );
        const twitterDescriptionCharactersCount = twitterDescription
          ? twitterDescription.length
          : 0;

        const ogImage = $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr("content");

        const ogUrl = $('meta[property="og:url"]').attr("content");

        const ogType = $('meta[property="og:type"]').attr("content");

        const canonicalUrl = $('link[rel="canonical"]').attr("href");

        const twitterCard = $('meta[name="twitter:card"]').attr("content");

        const twitterSite = $('meta[name="twitter:site"]').attr("content");

        const twitterCreator = $('meta[name="twitter:creator"]').attr(
          "content"
        );

        const ogLocale = $('meta[property="og:locale"]').attr("content");

        const ogImageWidth = $('meta[property="og:image:width"]').attr(
          "content"
        );

        const ogImageHeight = $('meta[property="og:image:height"]').attr(
          "content"
        );

        const num_of_h1 = $("h1").length;
        const h1_characters_count = $("h1").text().length;

        const num_of_h2 = $("h2").length;
        const num_of_h3 = $("h3").length;
        const num_of_h4 = $("h4").length;
        const num_of_h5 = $("h5").length;
        const num_of_h6 = $("h6").length;

        const num_of_images = $("img").length;
        const num_of_alt = $("img[alt]").length;

        const currentPage = {
          url,
          title,
          titleLength,
          metaDescription,
          metaDescriptionLength,
          ogTitle,
          ogTitleCharactersCount,
          twitterTitle,
          twitterTitleCharactersCount,
          ogDescription,
          ogDescriptionCharactersCount,
          twitterDescription,
          twitterDescriptionCharactersCount,
          ogImage,
          ogUrl,
          ogType,
          canonicalUrl,
          twitterCard,
          twitterSite,
          twitterCreator,
          ogLocale,
          ogImageWidth,
          ogImageHeight,
          num_of_h1,
          h1_characters_count,
          num_of_h2,
          num_of_h3,
          num_of_h4,
          num_of_h5,
          num_of_h6,
          num_of_images,
          num_of_alt,
        };
        console.log(currentPage); // Output the current page data (for debugging purposes)

        if (currentPage.url.startsWith(baseUrl)) {
          crawledPages.push(currentPage);
          await Crawledpage.create(currentPage);
          crawledPagesCount++;
        }

        // Follow links found on the page and crawl each linked page
        $("a").each((i, el) => {
          const href = $(el).attr("href");
          if (href && !href.startsWith("#")) {
            const linkedUrl = urlModule.resolve(url, href);
            crawl(linkedUrl, depth + 1);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.error(`Error crawling page: ${url}`);
      }
    });
  }

    crawl(baseUrl, 0);

  res.send("Crawling in progress"); // Return a response to the client indicating that crawling has started
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Rather than reinventing the wheel and making your own cralwer, have you considered using an [open-source crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers) instead?

I'd like to add [Norconex Web Crawler](https://opensource.norconex.com/crawlers/web/) to the mix as well. You can easily limit max pages with [maxDocuments](https://opensource.norconex.com/crawlers/web/v3/configuration#maxDocuments) param.
Disclaimer: I work for Norconex